# JAVA_HOME default in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu-14.04, java-home

I am using ubuntu 14.0.4... `JAVA_HOME` is always `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle` even though i uninstalled java...

I manually set `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_71` in `etc/environment`. But `$echo JAVA_HOME` shows `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle`.

How to resolve this issue and how to use my `jdk1.8.0_71` in `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/272187/setting-jdk-7-as-default) may help?

Answer (score 2):

Try edit `~/.profile`. 
Add line at bottom:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_71"
```

After editing, close console (terminal) window and open new. Test with echo JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 1):

from terminal:

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

than change:

```
export JAVA_HOME= path_to_java_here
```

than:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

verify with:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```